# Rotation of points in Android

Tags: android, math, geometry

[image]

I have point A, B and width of CD (A' = A). If user will move point B to B'how I can know coordinates of points C' D'. I would be very grateful if someone write method in java with 3 input parameters (A, B, and width of CD) which output coordinates of C' and D'. As reward I can pay 50$ via Paypal.

Comment: Try Fiverr or Upwork. This is a Q&A site for professional programmers!

Comment: Hi. Im a programmer myself. I need a help in this task.

Comment: Are they in 2D or 3D coordinates?

Answer (score 0):

The background:

First, if I understand correctly, the task actually is "given the coordinates of A and B, find coordinates of C and D if we know that AB and CD are perpendicular, and we know the length of CD"

To calculate the coordinates, we use 3 basic math equations:

- Line from 2 points A, B: `y = (x - B.x)* (A.y - B.y)/(A.x - B.x) + B.y`

  If we set `m = (A.y - B.y)/(A.x - B.x)`

The equation from 2 points A, B will be: `y = m * (x - B.x) + B.y`

- Line which is perpendicular with the line above (CD): `y =  (-1/m) * x + y0`

Since CD goes through A, the equation can be written as: `y = (-1/m) * (x - A.x) + A.y`

- The length (d) between 2 points A, C: `d * d = (C.x - A.x) * (C.x - A.x) + (C.y - A.y) * (C.y - A.y)`

From the equation of CD, we know `C.y = (-1/m)*(C.x - A.x) + A.y`

Therefore:
`d*d = (C.x - A.x)*(C.x - A.x) + (1/(m*m))*(C.x - A.x)* (C.x - A.x)`

Easily find out that `C.x - A.x = (+|-) (m*d)/Math.sqrt(m*m + 1)`

In java, I guess you can write the function as

```
public Point[] findCD(Point A, Point B, int widthCD) {
   if (A.x == B.x) {
      return [new Point(A.x - widthCD/2, A.y), new Point(A.x + widthCD/2, A.y)]
   }
   if (A.y == B.y) {
      return [new Point(A.x, A.y - widthCD/2), new Point(A.x, A.y + widthCD/2)]
   }
    
   var m = (A.y - B.y)/(A.x - B.x);

   var xC = A.x - m*widthCD/(2 * Math.sqrt(m*m + 1));
   var xD = A.x + m*widthCD/(2 * Math.sqrt(m*m + 1));

   var yC = (A.x - xC) / m + A.y;
   var yD = (A.x - xD) / m + A.y;

   return [new Point(xC, yC), new Point(xD, yD)];
}
```

**Note**: I don't have java, please correct if I write the pointer or array wrong